# How to enable SOAP tracing on Liberty running on IBMi

Tags: soap, ibm-midrange, websphere-liberty

How do I enable soap tracing on Liberty(19.0.0.1) that is running on IBMi (v7r2)?

I've tried adding 
`*=info: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all` via HTTP admin, but no trace of any SOAP messages is found.

EDIT:

HTTP Admin (IBM Web Administrator for i) > Server Properties > Server Tracing

Yes, I've added the asterisks but I'm new here and formatting kinda crooked it :)

Comment: Where in HTTP Admin did you attempt to add that trace string?

Comment: And do you see a `<logging traceSpecification...>` in server.xml, after having added it?

Comment: Assuming this got added to server.xml as dbreaux mentioned above, I believe you need to correct your trace string to =info: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all
You're missing an asterisk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there a few different ways to configure trace on Liberty, but I find adding  the  element to the server.xml is easiest (like one of the comments suggested). This element with the JAX-WS trace enabled on Liberty is:

`<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.jaxws.*=all:org.apache.cxf.*=all"/>`

This will print out lots of trace, but you can search for the SOAP Messages in the log files by searching for either/both:

`Inbound Message`  (The Request)

`Outbound Message` (The Response)

The logged request/response contents will include the SOAP Message.

For more info on configuring trace on Liberty check out: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you very much for help.

I used **Merged Trace** with `org.apache.cxf.*=all:com.ibm.ws.jaxws.*=all`

and that worked just fine.